# how to show cascade windows in Splitcontainer panel2 c#

Tags: c#, winforms

In `MdiParent toolstripmenuItem`, I'm writing the code to show all the windows in `cascade or Tile Horizontal` style.
My code is:

```
this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade);
this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.TileHorizontal);
```

This code will work in mdi parent only. But now I'm using a `Split container` in my Parent Form. In `Panel1` I have buttons to Show the Form. In `Panel2` My Forms will display, as:

```
        Forms.paymentPaid paidFm = new SalesandPurchases.Forms.paymentPaid();
        paidFm.MdiParent = this;
        paidFm.Left = (this.myPanel.Width - paidFm.Width) / 2;
        paidFm.Top = (this.myPanel.Height - paidFm.Height) / 2;
        myPanel.Controls.Add(paidFm);
        paidFm.Show();
```

Now Because of my `Split Container my code( this.LayoutMdi(MdiLayout.Cascade))` is not working for cascade the windows in `Panel2`. Please tell me any other  way.

Answer (score 1):

By merely changing the container of your controls without moving the MDI container itself will not work - as you have experienced. I think what you will need to do is to move your MDI container to the panel in which you want to display the child windows (panel 2). Basically you now want to have what you had before in the main window of your form in panel 2 of your split container.

I hope this helps.

Comment: How can i move my MDI Container to my SplitContainerPanel2 sir

Comment: The easiest way would be to do this in the designer. Select your MDI Container control and drag the handle to `Panel2`. This should place the control within your panel. You can then treat the MDI Container as you did before.